# 2D point cloud to shape contours for circle detection

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

I have a LRF that returns a 2D point cloud that I need to use to detect a circle (well, only a semi-circle is visible at any point in time). Using HoughCircles from OpenCV after a Canny and GaussianBlur returns a circle but even with hours of playing with values, it still returns false positives. Here's a section of the code that detects circles. `image` is basically the image of type `Mat` that is created from the LRF input.

```
cv::Mat destination;
cv::Canny(image, destination, 200, 20);
cv::GaussianBlur(destination, destination, Size(7, 7), 2, 2 );
vector<Vec3f> circles;
cv::HoughCircles(destination, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 100, 200, 15, 10, 20);
```

It can be assumed that there's ONLY one real circle in the point cloud. In most of the cases the it works fine[image: True positive]
But, from time to time false positives such as this happen.[image: False positive]

So far, I managed to reduce the number of circles at any  point to 1 by increasing the minDist parameter of HoughCircles to bigger than the image size but that still leads to false positives where it doesn't detect the actual circle. I think these false positives arise from the noise in the LRF input. Is there a way I can convert this point cloud image to an image with lines instead of points? so in case there's a circle detected in a place where there should be lines, I know it's a false positive. Or perhaps somebody has a better method that I've been missing all along.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try to convert it to binary image, with a threshold close to black. Lets say convert every pixel >50, or even lower, to white. It could help to eliminate the noise. Unfortunatelly, from my experience, this algorithm is never 100% reliable, especially with that much low thresholds, you use.

Comment: @j.kaspar The image is already B/W with W background and B dots. This image was generated by writing individual bits with black.